# Redirect to default dashboard route after successful AJAX login in Laravel 6

Tags: ajax, laravel, authentication, laravel-6

In my first Laravel 6 project I wrote a simple login form I submit via AJAX to standard login controller. If I insert correct credentials, login is successful but I don't know how to properly redirect to standard user dashboard (like standard Laravel 6 form do after successful login).
And I don't know how to properly manage unsuccessful login (wrong credentials) because I get "Unprocessable entity" error (status 422).

Form HTML and jQuery validation:

```
<style>
    .invalid-tooltip {
        font-size: 0.8rem;
        line-height: 1.1;
        background-color: #d9364fef;
    }
</style>
<form id="inlineLoginForm" method="POST" action="{{ route('login') }}">
    @csrf

    <div class="form-row align-items-center">

        <div class="col-auto">
            <label class="sr-only" for="email">{{ __('E-mail') }}</label>
            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}" placeholder="E-mail" autocomplete="email" autofocus>
            <div class="invalid-tooltip" role="alert"></div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-auto">
            <label class="sr-only" for="password">{{ __('Password') }}</label>
            <input type="password" class="form-control input-password" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" autocomplete="current-password">
            <span class="password-icon" aria-hidden="true">
                <svg class="password-icon-visible icon icon-sm"><use xlink:href="/svg/sprite.svg#it-password-visible"></use></svg>
                <svg class="password-icon-invisible icon icon-sm d-none"><use xlink:href="/svg/sprite.svg#it-password-invisible"></use></svg>
            </span>
            <div class="invalid-tooltip" role="alert"></div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-auto">
            <div class="form-check m-0">
                <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="remember" name="remember">
                <label class="form-check-label" for="remember">
                    {{ __('Ricordami') }}
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-auto">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">{{ __('Accedi') }}</button>
        </div>
    </div>

</form>

@section('scripts')
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#inlineLoginForm').validate({
                rules: {
                    email: {
                        required: true,
                        email: true
                    },
                    password: {
                        required: true
                    }
                },
                messages: {
                    email: {
                        required: "{{ __('Per favore inserisci il tuo indirizzo e-mail.') }}",
                        email: "{{ __('Per favore inserisci un indirizzo e-mail valido.') }}"
                    },
                    password: {
                        required: "{{ __('Per favore inserisci la password.') }}"
                    }
                },
                submitHandler: function(form) {
                    $.ajaxSetup({
                        headers: {
                            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': '{{ csrf_token() }}'
                        }
                    });

                    $.ajax({
                        type: "post",
                        url: "{{ route('login') }}",
                        data: $(form).serialize(),
                        success: function (response) {
                            console.log(response.errors.length);
                            location.reload({{ url('home') }});
                        },
                        error: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                            alert(textStatus + ': ' + jqXHR + ' (' + data + ')');
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
@endsection
```

**EDIT** (working solution as requested):

```
<form class="user" id="loginInlineForm" method="post" action="{{ route('login') }}">
    <div class="form-row align-items-center">
        <div class="col-auto">
            <label class="sr-only" for="email">{{ __('E-mail') }}</label>
            <div class="input-group mb-2">
                <input type="email" class="form-control form-control-user" id="email" name="email" placeholder="{{ __('E-mail') }}" autocomplete="email" autofocus>
                    <div class="invalid-tooltip order-last"></div>
                <div class="input-group-append">
                    <div class="input-group-text"><i class="fas fa-at"></i></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-auto">
            <div class="input-group mb-2">
                <input type="password" class="form-control form-control-user viewable-password" id="password" name="password" aria-label="User's password" placeholder="{{ __('Password') }}" autocomplete="current-password">
                <div class="invalid-tooltip order-last"></div>
                <div class="input-group-append">
                    <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" type="button" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="{{ __('Mostra/nascondi password') }}"><i class="far fa-eye"></i></button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-auto">
            <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox mb-2">
                <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="remember" name="remember">
                <label class="custom-control-label" for="remember">{{ __('Ricordami') }}</label>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-auto">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-user ml-3 mb-2">{{ __('Accedi') }}</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>

@section('scripts')
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#loginInlineForm').validate({
                rules: {
                    email: {
                        required: true,
                        email: true
                    },
                    password: {
                        required: true
                    }
                },
                messages: {
                    email: {
                        required: "{{ __('Per favore inserisci il tuo indirizzo e-mail.') }}",
                        email: "{{ __('Per favore inserisci un indirizzo e-mail valido.') }}"
                    },
                    password: {
                        required: "{{ __('Per favore inserisci la password.') }}"
                    }
                },
                submitHandler: function(form) {
                    $.ajaxSetup({
                        headers: {
                            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': '{{ csrf_token() }}'
                        }
                    });

                    $.ajax({
                        type: "post",
                        url: "{{ route('login') }}",
                        data: $(form).serialize(),
                        success: function () {
                            location.href = '{{ route('home') }}';
                        },
                        error: function (error) {
                            if (error.status === 422) {
                                let $alert = $('<div class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">\n' +
                                    '                <strong>{{ __('Accesso fallito!') }}</strong> {{ __('Non è stato trovato alcun utente con le credenziali specificate.') }}\n' +
                                    '                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">\n' +
                                    '                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>\n' +
                                    '                </button>\n' +
                                    '            </div>');
                                $('#loginFailureAlertContainer').prepend($alert);
                                setTimeout(function() {
                                    $alert.alert('close');
                                }, 6000);
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
@endsection
```

Comment: Can you please post login method ?

Comment: @vipertecpro I edited original post with the working login.

Answer (score 0):

When the for is submitted laravel will check credentials and return response to redirect to dashboard you will get this status as `succes:

```
<style>
    .invalid-tooltip {
        font-size: 0.8rem;
        line-height: 1.1;
        background-color: #d9364fef;
    }
</style>
<form id="inlineLoginForm" method="POST" action="{{ route('login') }}">
    @csrf

    <div class="form-row align-items-center">

        <div class="col-auto">
            <label class="sr-only" for="email">{{ __('E-mail') }}</label>
            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}" placeholder="E-mail" autocomplete="email" autofocus>
            <div class="invalid-tooltip" role="alert"></div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-auto">
            <label class="sr-only" for="password">{{ __('Password') }}</label>
            <input type="password" class="form-control input-password" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" autocomplete="current-password">
            <span class="password-icon" aria-hidden="true">
                <svg class="password-icon-visible icon icon-sm"><use xlink:href="/svg/sprite.svg#it-password-visible"></use></svg>
                <svg class="password-icon-invisible icon icon-sm d-none"><use xlink:href="/svg/sprite.svg#it-password-invisible"></use></svg>
            </span>
            <div class="invalid-tooltip" role="alert"></div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-auto">
            <div class="form-check m-0">
                <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="remember" name="remember">
                <label class="form-check-label" for="remember">
                    {{ __('Ricordami') }}
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-auto">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">{{ __('Accedi') }}</button>
        </div>
    </div>

</form>

@section('scripts')
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#inlineLoginForm').validate({
                rules: {
                    email: {
                        required: true,
                        email: true
                    },
                    password: {
                        required: true
                    }
                },
                messages: {
                    email: {
                        required: "{{ __('Per favore inserisci il tuo indirizzo e-mail.') }}",
                        email: "{{ __('Per favore inserisci un indirizzo e-mail valido.') }}"
                    },
                    password: {
                        required: "{{ __('Per favore inserisci la password.') }}"
                    }
                },
                submitHandler: function(form) {
                    $.ajaxSetup({
                        headers: {
                            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': '{{ csrf_token() }}'
                        }
                    });

                    $.ajax({
                        type: "post",
                        url: "{{ route('login') }}",
                        data: $(form).serialize(),
                        success: function (response) {
                            console.log(response.errors.length);
                            location.href = '{{ url('home') }}';
                        },
                        error: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                            alert(textStatus + ': ' + jqXHR + ' (' + data + ')');
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
@endsection
```

When success status returned you can redirect user using `location.href = 'someurl'`.

IF something error hapenned or user provided wrong credentials you will get error which you can handle with `error:` in your ajax request and let the user know that provided credentials was wrong

Comment: Thank you for reply but can you check it please? I think there are some typos...

Comment: You mean this? `location.href = '{{ url('home') }}';` . This is not typo since this is blade file and will be rendered to this: `location.href = 'http://example.com/homeurlhere'` but you can single any single quote pair to double quotes. `location.href = '{{ url("home") }}';`

Comment: no, I mean when you write "and return response to redirect to dashboard you will get this status as `succes:", can you specify better the status returned?

Comment: If credentials are correct you will get http 302 redirect code and your ajax will fire success event. If you want more specifies you can write in your ajax this: `statusCode:{ 302:function(){ alert("correct credentials"); // redirect here } }`

Comment: If you want to get the url where your laravel app redirected you can use `getResponseHeader`  method. For example: `success: function(data, textStatus, request){
        document.location.href = request.getResponseHeader('location');
   }`

Comment: Ok, for redirect after successful login I used `location.reload({{ route('home') }});` and it works but why if I use uncorrect credentials `error: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){...}` instead of `success: function (response){...}` with reponse = to error status?

Comment: If error hapenned on the server ajax won't fire success event, instead error is fired. So you can't do "reponse = to error status"

Comment: I wrote: `statusCode:{ 422:function(response) {
                            if (response.responseJSON.errors.email[0] === 'These credentials do not match our records.') {
                                alert('These credentials do not match our records.');
                            }
                        }}`

Comment: I am glad to help you. Please consider to upvote and accept answer. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**for redirect after success login : **

```
window.location.replace({{url("home"}});
```

**for check common error : **

```
error: function(error) {
  switch(error.response.status){
      case 422:
         // your code
       break;
     case 401:
       // your code
      break; 
      ...

  }
}
```